# Dynamic Fields in Bottom to Right responsive layout columns

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, responsive

How can I achieve having responsive columns (max 5), when my fields are displayed dynamically going to bottom to right:

[image]

But when the window size is reduced, the layout should become

[image]

How can I do this in bootstrap?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a code to start with ? Have you tried flexbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS3 multiple column layout`:

**Html**:

`<ul>
  <li>field1</li>
  <li>field2</li>
  <li>field3</li>
  ...
</ul>`

**CSS**:

`ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  -moz-column-width: 150px;
  column-width: 150px;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}`

For the browser support check [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn). Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/5kaayaas/)